# Datomic Ions: Connecting to on-prem database

Tags: clojure, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, datomic

I am trying to connect my Datomic Ions app to an on-prem Datomic DB running on DynamoDB. When I run `(datomic.api/connect "datomic:ddb://us-west-2/***/***")` I am getting the following error: `Could not initialize class datomic.Peer`

deps.edn is as follows

```
 :deps {com.datomic/ion {:mvn/version "0.9.28"}
        org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "0.2.6"}
        org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.9.0"}
        com.datomic/client-cloud {:mvn/version "0.8.71"}
        com.datomic/datomic-pro {:mvn/version "0.9.5697"}
        com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb {:mvn/version "1.11.33"}
        com.datomic/client-impl-pro {:mvn/version "0.8.7"}}
 :mvn/repos {"datomic-cloud" {:url "s3://datomic-releases-1fc2183a/maven/releases"}}
 :aliases
 {:dev {:extra-deps {com.datomic/client-cloud {:mvn/version "0.8.71"}
                     com.datomic/ion-dev {:mvn/version "0.9.186"}}}}}
```

Comment: probably makes sense to take this to the datomic list? https://forum.datomic.com - my suspicion is that mixing the cloud client with on-prem is currently unsupported.